# Como adicionar dependências em um módulo já inicializado em AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu costumo usar AngularJS com uma estrutura onde eu tenho um script Javascript para cada pagina da minha aplicação.

As dependências principais e configurações do projeto eu defino num arquivo `app.js`, que é usado em todas as páginas.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
// 'js/app.js'

angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.validate'])


// 'js/usuarios/listar.js'

angular.module('app').controller('UsuariosController', function () {
      // resto do código
})
```

Ou seja, eu sempre adiciondo ao módulo existente `app` uma funcionalidade de acordo com a página que eu carrego (não estou usando SPA).

Assim sendo, necessito carregar no módulo `app` uma dependência  específica, para um determinado script.

No caso do script `js/usuarios/editar.js` preciso adicionar `ngFileUpload`.

Não gostaria de adicionado ao meu `app.js` padrão, já que eu não vou fazer upload de arquivos em todas as páginas da minha aplicação, mas apenas nessa específica onde uso `js/usuarios/editar.js`.

É possível adicionar uma dependência em um módulo do angular que já foi inicializado?

Comment: Pelo que vi em alguns links e sites, você vai ter que declarar no arquivo geral mesmo se usar apenas em um módulo/controller só.

Comment: @mutlei errado. Eu já consegui fazer isso :p

Comment: Então... você não tem mais um trecho do código que permite fazer isso?

Comment: @mutlei se quiser fazer o [favor de traduzir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244717/3096922), ajudará a comunidade:

Comment: Traduzido, caro Wallace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tradução [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988989/add-dependency-to-angular-module-after-its-been-created/37244717#37244717)

Eu uso o seguinte método e funciona bem comigo:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").requires.push('ngResource');
```

Caso você precise colocar mais de uma dependencia no mesmo módulo, você pode extender os argumentos do push()

```
angular.module("myApp").requres.push('dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3');
```

Comment: Alterado com as suas sugestões